# Javascript search in array of json with multi parametes one of them is array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, data-structures

Hello I have the following complicated array of json

```
const cardItems = [
  { item_id: 1, item_name: 'pize', varation_id: 3, addOns: [1,2,3,4,5], quantity: 1 },
  { item_id: 1, item_name: 'pize', varation_id: 1, addOns: [1,2,3,4,5], quantity: 1}, 
  { item_id: 1, item_name: 'pize', varation_id: 1, addOns: [1,2,3,4], quantity: 1 }
  { item_id: 2, item_name: 'shawrma', varation_id: 2, addOns: [1,2,4], quantity: 1 },  
  { item_id: 2, item_name: 'shawrma', varation_id: 2, addOns: [1,4], quantity: 1 },  
  { item_id: 3, item_name: 'pize', varation_id: 9, addOns: [1,2,4,5], quantity: 2 }, 
  { item_id: 4, item_name: 'shawrma', varation_id: 2, addOns: [1,2,4], quantity: 1 }
]
```

The incoming item will be like below:

```
{ item_id: 1, item_name: 'any thing', varation_id: 1, addOns: [1,2,3,4], quantity: 1 }
```

I want to make checking in the array and do the following:

- If the incoming item does not exist in the array add it as a new one
- If the incoming item have the same `item_id`, `varation_id`, and `addOns` (even if not same sort) just increase the quantity
- If the incoming item is the same `item_id` but `varation_id` or `addOns` (even if not same sort) not equally insert item as a new one

Prefer `lodash` to do the condition in one line ^_^

Comment: I am okay with lodash library

Answer (score 0):

```
let cardItems = [
    {item_id:1, item_name:"pize", varation_id:3, addOns:[1,2,3,4,5], quantity:1}, 
    {item_id:1, item_name:"pize", varation_id:1, addOns:[1,2,3,4,5], quantity:1}, 
    {item_id:1, item_name:"pize", varation_id:1, addOns:[1,2,3,4], quantity:1},
    {item_id:2, item_name:"shawrma", varation_id:2, addOns:[1,2,4], quantity:1},  
    {item_id:2, item_name:"shawrma", varation_id:2, addOns:[1,4], quantity:1},  
    {item_id:3, item_name:"pize", varation_id:9, addOns:[1,2,4,5], quantity:2}, 
    {item_id:4, item_name:"shawrma", varation_id:2, addOns:[1,2,4], quantity:1}];

    function arraysEqual(_arr1, _arr2) {

        if (!Array.isArray(_arr1) || !Array.isArray(_arr2) || _arr1.length !== _arr2.length)
          return false;

        var arr1 = _arr1.concat().sort();
        var arr2 = _arr2.concat().sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
                return false;

        }

        return true;

    }

const addItem = (itemId, varationId, addOns) => {
        let excistingItemIndex = cardItems.findIndex(item => {return (item.item_id === itemId
                 && item.varation_id === varationId
                 && arraysEqual(item.addOns, addOns))})
            console.log(excistingItemIndex)
        let excistingItem = cardItems[excistingItemIndex]
        let updatedItem;

        if(excistingItem) {
            updatedItem = {...excistingItem};
            updatedItem.quantity = updatedItem.quantity + 1;
            cardItems[excistingItemIndex] = updatedItem
        }else{
            updatedItem = {item_id:itemId, varation_id: varationId, addOns:addOns, quantity: 1}
            cardItems = [...cardItems, updatedItem]
        }

}
```

Comment: can we do it with lodash in one line by equale?

Answer (score 0):

```
const cartItems = ...
const newItem = ...
let sortedAddons = newItem.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
let found = false;

cartItems.forEach(({item_id, varation_id, addOns }, index)=>{
  if(item_id === newItem.item_id && 
     varation_id === newItem.varation_id &&
     !addons.sort((a,b)=>a-b).some((el, i)=> el !== sortedAddons[i])&&
     addons.length === sortedAddons.length
  ){
   cartItems[index].quantity += newItem.quantity;
   found = true;
  }
})
if(!found){
   cartItems.push(newItem);
}
```

With lodash

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const cartItems = ...
const newItem = ...
let sortedAddons = newItem.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
let found = false;

cartItems.forEach((item, index)=>{
  if(_.isEqual({...newItem, addOns:sortedAddons },
    {...item, addOns:item.addOns.sort((a,b)=>a-b)}))
  ){
   cartItems[index].quantity += newItem.quantity;
   found = true;
  }
})
if(!found){
   cartItems.push(newItem);
}
```

Comment: can do with lodash, equal or compare?

Comment: what does mean? !addons.sort((a,b)=>a-b).some((el, index)=> el !== sortedAddons[index])&&
     addons.length === sortedAddons.length

Comment: `addons.length === sortedAddons.length` addons has to be the same length to be equal

Comment: `!addons.sort((a,b)=>a-b).some((el, index)=> el !== sortedAddons[index])` we sort addons then compare them to new item's addons. `Some` is a function that returns boolean.If any item meets condition it short circuits. `el !== sortedAddons[i]` will return true if there is some inequality. If `el !== sortedAddons[i]` fails on every single item (and addons are the same), the function will return false. That's why we put `!` in front of the `addons.sort...some()` ,to make it a positive statement

Answer (score 0):

```
const cardItems = [
    { item_id: 1, item_name: "piza", varation_id: 3, addOns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
quantity: 1 },
    { item_id: 2, item_name: "piza", varation_id: 1, addOns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
quantity: 1 },
]

const item = { item_id: 1, item_name: "piza", varation_id: 3, addOns: [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], 
quantity: 1 };


const Index = cardItems.findIndex(foundproduct => foundproduct.item_id === 
item.item_id);

if (Index >= 0) {
    //item found
    if (cardItems[Index].varation_id === item.varation_id && 
JSON.stringify(cardItems[Index].addOns.sort()) === JSON.stringify(item.addOns.sort())) 
{
        //item is the same
       //add quantity only
        cardItems[Index].quantity = cardItems[Index].quantity + item.quantity;
        console.log(cardItems);
    }
    else {
        //insert item as new one
        cardItems.push(item);
        console.log(cardItems);
    }
}
else {
    //item not found
   //add item to array
    cardItems.push(item);
    console.log(cardItems);
}
```

that is using only the find index .

Answer (score 0):

```
const cardItems = [
    { item_id: 1, item_name: "piza", varation_id: 3, addOns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
quantity: 1 },
    { item_id: 2, item_name: "piza", varation_id: 1, addOns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
quantity: 1 },
]

const item = { item_id: 1, item_name: "piza", varation_id: 3, addOns: [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], 
quantity: 1 };


const foundItemIndex = cardItems.findIndex(foundproduct => foundproduct.item_id === 
item.item_id);
const foundItem = cardItems.find(objectItem => objectItem.item_id === item.item_id);

if (foundItem) {
    //item found
    if (foundItem.varation_id === item.varation_id && 
 JSON.stringify(foundItem.addOns.sort()) === JSON.stringify(item.addOns.sort())) {
        //item is the same
       //add quantity only
        cardItems[foundItemIndex].quantity = cardItems[foundItemIndex].quantity + 
item.quantity;
        console.log(cardItems);

    }
    else {
        //insert item as new one
        cardItems.push(item);
        console.log(cardItems);
    }
}
else {
    //item not found
   //add item to array
    cardItems.push(item);
    console.log(cardItems);
}
```

that using find index & find (less preformance than index only because of the 2 loops here and the other is with one loop )

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code snippet.

```js
let cardItems = [
  {item_id:1, item_name:'pize', varation_id:3, addOns:[1,2,3,4,5], quantity:1},
  {item_id:1, item_name:'pize', varation_id:1, addOns:[1,2,3,4,5], quantity:1},
  {item_id:1, item_name:'pize', varation_id:1, addOns:[1,2,3,4], quantity:1},
  {item_id:2, item_name:'shawrma', varation_id:2, addOns:[1,2,4], quantity:1},
  {item_id:2, item_name:'shawrma', varation_id:2, addOns:[1,4], quantity:1},
  {item_id:3, item_name:'pize', varation_id:9, addOns:[1,2,4,5], quantity:2},
  {item_id:4, item_name:'shawrma', varation_id:2, addOns:[1,2,4], quantity:1}
]

function compareArray(a, b) {
  if (a.length != b.length) return false
  for (const i of a) {
    if (b.indexOf(i) < 0) return false
  }
  return true
}

function addItem(newItem) {
  for (const item of cardItems) {
    if (item.item_id == newItem.item_id && item.varation_id == newItem.varation_id && compareArray(item.addOns, newItem.addOns) == true) {
      item.quantity++
      return
    }
  }
  cardItems.push(newItem)
}

addItem({item_id:1, item_name:'any thing', varation_id:1, addOns:[1,2,3,4], quantity:1})

console.log(cardItems)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need bro ;)

```
const addProductToCart = (product, state) => {
  const updatedCart = [...state.cart]
  const updatedItemIndex = updatedCart.findIndex(item => item._id === product._id)

  if (updatedItemIndex < 0) {
    updatedCart.push({ ...product, quantity: 1 })
  } else {
    const updatedItem = {
      ...updatedCart[updatedItemIndex],
    }
    updatedItem.quantity++
    updatedCart[updatedItemIndex] = updatedItem
  }
  return { ...state, cart: updatedCart }
}

const removeProductFromCart = (productId, state) => {
  console.log('Removing product with id: ' + productId)
  const updatedCart = [...state.cart]
  const updatedItemIndex = updatedCart.findIndex(item => item._id === productId)

  const updatedItem = {
    ...updatedCart[updatedItemIndex],
  }
  updatedItem.quantity--
  if (updatedItem.quantity <= 0) {
    updatedCart.splice(updatedItemIndex, 1)
  } else {
    updatedCart[updatedItemIndex] = updatedItem
  }
  return { ...state, cart: updatedCart }
}
```

and then inside you reducer you will need to pass `productID` and `state`:

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PRODUCT:
      return addProductToCart(action.product, state)
    case REMOVE_PRODUCT:
      return removeProductFromCart(action.productId, state)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

HAPPY CODING